# Mail not getting send to specific domains

Tags: email, dns, centos, vps, directadmin

We have a VPS with CentOS combined with DirectAdmin which we use for a Magento shop. This runs fine, except for sending email.

**Problem:**
It appears that some specific domains won't receive our emails and we get a bounce. If we use any other email sending systems, the mails arrive without problems.

The bounce mail contains the following error:

> SMTP error from remote mail server after HELO Company-Shops:
>   host mx-cluster-b2.one.com [*IP ADRESS*]: 504 5.5.2 :
>   Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname

After googling and trying things for a week now, I am a bit lost. I tried checking postfix in CentOS, but this is not installed and I'm not quite sure if this is needed.

**Possible issue?**
I believe the hostfile in CentOS is setup incorrectly:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 ... etc
>   *OUR IP* Company-Shops

'Company-Shops' should probably be a domain name, am I right? The same as the rDNS. But I'm afraid if I change this it will kill my site and whatnot. I'm not sure if this entry correlates with the 'company-Shops' helo label in the bounce error.

**Some extra info:**
- We use the webmail Roundcube from DirectAdmin
- At the moment we run one shop, but this might grow a bit (multiple sites on 1 IP)
- We don't use subdomains 
- We've set up a reverse DNS, with the domain

Is there anyone with similiar experiences or with a bit more knowledge about this subject? I appreciate any advice we can get, as we are stuck..

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right: your mail server should identify itself using a fully-qualified domain name when it connects to send mail via SMTP. You don't say what mail server you're running, but since you're using DA, it's probably Exim. If so, you want to edit /etc/exim.conf and set primary_hostname to the FQDN of your server.

This would also be a good time to double-check that reverse DNS is set up properly for your IP address. Many hosts will also reject email from servers on IPs without a valid rDNS record.

I'm not familiar with Magento, but I can't see any way that changing the Exim configuration in this way could impact that program.